# multiple bash commands in a single line in python

Tags: python

We have multiple bash commands like

```
cd /home/ ; ls -lrt abc* ; cp abc* /destination/ ; ....
```

we can run multiple commands in the bash as per above using ";"

can we run in the same way in python ? (something all the commands into a variable and execute using os or subprocess)

Is there a way to run all these commands in a single line in python

Comment: Of course. The argument to `os.system()` can be any shell command line, including multiple commands separated by `;`.

Comment: @Barmar .. Is that something i can give in this way --- >  os.system("ls lrt abc*; cp abc* /destination")

Comment: Ravi: Can't you just try it and see for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `subprocess` python library

```
import subprocess

command = "cd /home/ ; ls -lrt abc* ; cp abc* /destination/ ; ...."

ret = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, shell=True)


print(ret.stdout.decode())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html